# First Angular2 example app not working

Tags: node.js, angular

I just started a course on Udemy for Angular2. The instructor included a seed project to get started with. I’m trying to run “npm install” to get it to install all the modules in the package.json. After running the install the “node_modules” folder never gets installed.

Here are the steps I took. 
1.  Downloaded the code.zip file and extracted files to a folder. 
2.  Created a new “Empty Web” project in Visual Studio.
3.  Copied the files into the project.
4.  Opened up a command prompt, went to the folder where package.json was located, ran “npm install”

When I go look at the folder structure there isn’t a node_modules folder created.

I then looked at the npm-debug.log and I see a bunch of errors about “Certificate has expired”. Then ultimately I see where it ran “rollbackFailedOptional”. Here is some of that log file.

```
155 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Error (native)
155 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1079:38)
155 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
155 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
155 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:603:8)
155 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:433:38)
155 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for rxjs@5.0.0-beta.2 { Error: certificate has expired
155 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Error (native)
155 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1079:38)
155 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
155 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
155 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:603:8)
155 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:433:38) code: 'CERT_HAS_EXPIRED' }
156 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
157 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
158 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
159 silly install printInstalled
160 verbose stack Error: certificate has expired
160 verbose stack     at Error (native)
160 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1079:38)
160 verbose stack     at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
160 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
160 verbose stack     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:603:8)
160 verbose stack     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:433:38)
161 verbose cwd C:\DevExampleProjects\Angular2-Seed-Udemy\Angular2-Seed-Udemy
162 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
163 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
164 error node v6.9.2
165 error npm  v3.10.9
166 error code CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
```

Comment: I'm sure you have already considered this, but have you contacted Udemy regarding this issue?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to contact the instructor but that can take a while to get any information back and that's if he even takes the time to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned that you are using Visual studio IDE, Instead of command prompt alternatively can you try restoring the packages by right clicking on "package.json" file. once you restore the packages then click on "show all files" in visual studio. node_modules will be shown as hidden folder. Please let me know if are getting the same issue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did do the restore on the package.json in VS but unfortunately go the same error.

Comment: AS per the log, it is showing that npm license certification has expired. Can you try to resolve the issue by using the "npm config set strict-ssl false" command as a workaround for now?

Comment: Thanks, thank changed some things. Now I'm getting "npm ERR! registry error parsing json". That's inside of VS 2015. Now when I run "npm install" from a command prompt I got a bunch of HTML returned that looks like it was from the network I'm on. I think I'm going to have to try this on my home network. My work one my be locked down too much.

Comment: ok. run the command---   npm config set registry "registry.npmjs.org/";    ---- it will install the packages using http instead of https

Comment: tried that and it still didn't work. I still haven't tried it on my home network but hope to do that this weekend. I'm keeping these commands in my notes though because I think the will definitely come in handy.